# Obtener un dato a partir de otra tabla en SQL

Tags: sql

Tengo las siguientes tablas creadas en **SQL/MySQL**:

**Comunidades**:

```
CREATE TABLE comunidades (
    id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    comunidad varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL UNIQUE KEY,
    capital_id int(11) NOT NULL
);
```

**Provincias**:

```
CREATE TABLE  provincias (
    id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    provincia varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
    comunidad_id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    capital_id int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT "-1",
    FOREIGN KEY (comunidad_id) REFERENCES comunidades(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Por ejemplo con los siguientes datos:

```
SELECT p.* FROM provincias AS p, comunidades AS c WHERE c.comunidad = 'ANDALUCIA' AND c.id=p.comunidad_id;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Teniendo en cuenta que todas las provincias de Andalucia pertenecen al "`id`" 1, y que `capital_id` de Sevilla es 6152 al igual que el `capital_id` de Andalucia.

**Dada una comunidad autónoma, ¿como puedo sacar su capital?**

Comment: Considera agregar la tabla de capitales

Comment: @BetaM Teniendo en cuenta que todas las provincias de Andalucia pertenecen al "id" 1, y que capital_id de Sevilla es 6152 al igual que el capital_id de Andalucia, ¿no se puede obtener con una relación?

Comment: Como te indica @BetaM, tienes que tener una tabla ciudades con un `id` que sea ese 6152 al que haces referencia

Comment: Agrega ese detalle y te ayudamos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considerando que necesariamente tiene que existir una tabla `ciudades` tal que así:

```
CREATE TABLE ciudades(
  id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  ciudad varchar(127)
  );

INSERT INTO comunidades (id, comunidad, capital_id) VALUES
  (1,'Andalucía',6152),
  (3,'Asturias',5009),
  (6,'Cantabria',5823);
INSERT INTO ciudades (id, ciudad) VALUES
  (6152,'Sevilla'),
  (5009,'Oviedo'),
  (5823,'Santander');
```

La consulta que buscas sería más o menos así:

```
SELECT ciudad FROM (
    SELECT * FROM comunidades
      WHERE comunidad='Andalucía'
  ) comunidades JOIN ciudades
  ON capital_id=ciudades.id;
```

Una vez que tienes el id de la ciudad, sólo tienes que combinar ambas tablas.

También la puedes obtener así:

```
SELECT ciudad FROM ciudades WHERE id=(
    SELECT capital_id FROM comunidades
      WHERE comunidad='Andalucía'
  );
```

O así:

```
SELECT ciudad FROM comunidades JOIN ciudades
  ON capital_id=ciudades.id
  WHERE comunidad='Andalucía';
```

Todas son equivalentes.

Lo que te está desorientando es que, tanto la autonomía de Andalucía como la provincia de Sevilla, tienen la misma capital: la ciudad de Sevilla. Son entidades diferentes con IDs diferentes

Comment: ¿Entonces es necesaria la tabla ciudades/capitales, una tabla intermedia?

Comment: ¿Entonces las 3 tablas: comunidades, provincias y capitales?

Comment: Efectivamente, una similar a la que aporto en la respuesta. Bueno, intermedia no, la de provincias no tiene nada que ver con la consulta que planteas

Comment: Pensé que habría una manera de añadir el id de la capital automáticamente y no ir mirando cuál corresponde a cuál... ¿Mis dos tablas son correctas la estructura? @DavidJP

Comment: Las dos tablas que tienes son correctas, cada una es para lo que es. Pero tu base de datos está incompleta, te faltan las ciudades